# Image size increases when data is retrieved from UIImage

Tags: ios, swift

When I load an image from a file path into a `UIImage`, the size ends up increasing. Am I doing something wrong?

```
let imageData = try! Data(contentsOf: imageUrl)
print("Original file size : \(imageData.count.readableSize())") // Displays 2.34 MB

let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageUrl.path)
print("UIImage file size : \(image.pngData()!.readableSize())") // Displays 5.71 MB

extension Int
{
    func readableSize() -> String
    {
        let units = ["bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB"]

        var count = 0
        var readableFileSize = self

        while readableFileSize > 1024
        {
            readableFileSize = readableFileSize/1024
            count += 1
        }

        return String(format: "%.2f", readableFileSize) + " " + units[count]
    }
}
```

In the above code sample, assume that the image loaded is of png format.

I am looking for a way to circumvent this and get the actual data that was initially loaded

Edit: I'm trying to load an image into `UIImage`, resize it and then save it back into the file system. I'm looking for a way to achieve this without increasing the size of the file because of what I have described. I'm open to even an alternative to resize without loading the image into UIImage.

Comment: png is stored as compressed data so I assume the data in `image` is uncompressed since UIImage unlike Data knows about the png file format.

Comment: If so, how am I to get the actual image data? Cause saving it back increases the size of the image stored within the application

Comment: Not sure what you mean since UIImage is immutable. If you want to store it locally shouldn't you read as Data then, that is your `imageData`object, and then load that when you want to use the image

Comment: Yes, i do edit the image. I resize the image to certain pre-defined values before saving it

Comment: I use `pngData()` function which's the same as `UIImagePNGRepresentation`. So, yes

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it does not answer your question but I want to share some useful information.

**Code:**

```
let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let fileName = "2.png"
let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName)

let imageData = try! Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
print("Original file size : \(imageData.count/1024)")

let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: fileURL.path)
print("UIImage file size : \(image!.pngData()!.count/1024)")
```

**Debug log as you mentioned in your question(size is different):**

```
Original file size : 6083
UIImage file size : 14982
```

**Conclusion:**

> After lot's of research and frustration, I realized that the size of
>   an image in document directory **(14982)** and size image from data is
>   identical **(14982)** that's mean when we are getting data from `URL` automatically compress it by the system.

Comment: Thanks for verifying what I had said. In my case though, the original file size from the document directory matches 6083 (in your case) and not 14982. The size of the file increases if we read the image data, convert it to UIImage and write it back

Comment: So, based on your recent edit, the size of image from UIImage is 6083? Can you please clarify? Has the size increased or not. It'd be great if you can make your conclusion clearer.

Comment: Changes were made accidentally. Keep size to 14982

Comment: The conclusion is unclear, please edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let remoteImageData = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/b/bb/Png-logo.png")!)
print(remoteImageData)

if let imageFileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Png-logo", withExtension: "png") {
    let imageFileData = try? Data(contentsOf: imageFileUrl)
    print(imageFileData)
}
```

Prints:

```
Optional(811068 bytes)
Optional(811068 bytes)
```

Comment: You haven't loaded the data or url to UIImage in either case. That is where the problem arises. 
Read the image from url or data into UIImage, convert it back to data and print the sizes. Those do not match for me